# Android MediaPlayer not working on Samsung phones or tablets

Tags: android, media-player

The player code is not working on Samsung phones or tablets. If anyone has an idea as to why this is.

I also downloaded a open source player from here, tested it so it's not my code...anyone have an idea why?

https://github.com/scampion/Radio-SingSing-Android

Tested on a samsung vibrant with updated 2.2 using standard android  MediaPlayer.